# Bootstrap template won't open in domain name

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have uploaded a bootstrap zip file to the public html folder in cpanel but when I go to load the webpage it only brings me to index of `/` and then presents the list of folders in the public html `CSS`, `JS` `index.html` etc. It is only when I click on the `index.html` that my webpage actually appears.

Have I uploaded the bootstrap zip incorrectly?

Comment: did you extract the zip file in your host ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A website will automatically look for the 'homepage' as any valid index file in the root folder (`index.html`, `index.php`, etc). Assuming you have successfully extracted `index.html` to `http://www.example.com/index.html`, you should also be able to access the page at `http://www.example.com`. You may need to look into `.htaccess` for a configuration issue, or possibly wait for your webhost to 'propagate' (unlikely).

Comment: thanks! got it working now.